# storing the employee data in a map in java

Tags: java

In an interview it was asked to design a POJO named `Employee` which consists of three fields:

1. name
2. job
3. salary

And then store it in a set and then remove the objects for which I 
have design the program as shown below

but later on they have asked me to store it in has map also
now my problem is that what should i use as key in map since in this case the name job salary cab be same also so what shall i use as a key in hash map

```
class Emp
  implements Comparable
{
  String name;
  String job;
  int salary;

  public Emp(String paramString1, String paramString2, int paramInt)
  {
    this.name = paramString1;
    this.job = paramString2;
    this.salary = paramInt;
  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println(this.name + "\t" + this.job + "\t" + this.salary);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object paramObject) {
    Emp localEmp = (Emp)paramObject;
    return (this.name.equals(localEmp.name)) && (this.job.equals(localEmp.job)) && (this.salary == localEmp.salary);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return this.name.hashCode() + this.job.hashCode() + this.salary;
  }

  public int compareTo(Object paramObject) {
    Emp localEmp = (Emp)paramObject;
    return this.name.compareTo(localEmp.name);
  }
}
```

and the main class is

```
class EmpHsDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    HashSet localHashSet = new HashSet();
    localHashSet.add(new Emp("Ram", "Trainer", 34000));
    localHashSet.add(new Emp("Ravi", "Administrator", 44000));
    localHashSet.add(new Emp("Sachin", "Programmer", 24000));
    localHashSet.add(new Emp("Priyanka", "Manager", 54000));
    localHashSet.add(new Emp("Anupam", "Programmer", 34000));
    localHashSet.add(new Emp("Sachin", "Team Leader", 54000));
    System.out.println("There are " + localHashSet.size() + " elements in the set.");
    System.out.println("Content of set are : ");
    Iterator localIterator = localHashSet.iterator();
    while (localIterator.hasNext())
    {
      localEmp1 = (Emp)localIterator.next();
      System.out.print(localEmp1.hashCode() + "\t");
      localEmp1.display();
    }
    Emp localEmp1 = new Emp("Ravi", "Administrator", 44000);
    System.out.println("Removing following Emp from the set...");
    System.out.print(localEmp1.hashCode() + "\t");
    localEmp1.display();
    localHashSet.remove(localEmp1);
    System.out.println("No. of elements after removal " + localHashSet.size());
    Emp localEmp2 = new Emp("Anupam", "Programmer", 34000);
    System.out.println("Searching following Emp in the set...");
    System.out.print(localEmp2.hashCode() + "\t");
    localEmp2.display();
    System.out.println("Results of searching is : " + localHashSet.contains(localEmp2));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think a combination string of all three fields could be the key like 'Ram-Trainer-34000'.

Comment: I'll put it like this:  your `compareTo` is incomplete; it doesn't take into account `null`, nor does it make use of generics anywhere.  Right now, you've got a chance for a `ClassCastException` due to the fact that your `compareTo` doesn't take an `Emp` object.

Comment: ...then I look up and I see raw types kind of...everywhere...hm.

Answer (score 3):

Your current `Emp` class could have problems even when used in a `HashSet`, since two employees with the same name can work in the same company for the same salary, and the `HashSet` won't be able to distinguish between them.

You should add some unique identifier to the `Emp` class. That unique member can serve as the key in a `Map`. It can also be used in the calculation of `hashCode` and `equals` (instead of the other properties), since it uniquely identifies the employee.

Answer (score 3):

Actually keys in `HashMap` is a similar thing to values in `HashSet`, there is no big difference between them. The only question what is unique constraints for your object, I would ask interviewer about that and suggest to use either **name** or add some additional unique identifier (e.g. **id**). If it is **name + salary + job** then you should use them to create `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Once these methods correctly defined - you can use `Employee` class itself as a HashMap key with no doubts.

Lets's say we decided that name + salary + job is our unique identificator, then we can define **hashCode/equals** as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Employee employee = (Employee) o;

    if (job != null ? !job.equals(employee.job) : employee.job != null) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(employee.name) : employee.name != null) return false;
    if (salary != null ? !salary.equals(employee.salary) : employee.salary != null) return false;

    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (job != null ? job.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (salary != null ? salary.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Now we can use Employee as a key in a Hash based structures. We can create HashSet and HashMap:

```
    List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee("name", "job", 100),
            new Employee("name", "job2", 300),
            new Employee("name2", "job", 200)
    );
    Set<Employee> hashSet = new HashSet<Employee>(employeeList);
    Map<Employee, Employee> hashMap = new HashMap<Employee, Employee>();
    for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
        hashMap.put(employee, employee);
    }
```

Going further to the source code of the HashSet - we see that it actually use a HashMap inside and add our values as a HashMap's keys with a dummy internal object as each Map's entry value, check the **constructor** and **add** method:

```
public HashSet() {
map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
}

public boolean add(E e) {
return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Comment: ok can you please show also how can i use employee object as a key that would bring more clarity please

Comment: I've added more details

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map as follows

```
 Map<String, Emp> m = new Hashtable<>();
```

and you can assign each employee a employee id and store the corresponding employee object to the map.

Answer (score 0):

@udalmik 
Please try to get the value in hashmap using get(key) it will not be possible because the class Employee is mutable . You should make it immutable with final keyword.